# Where did the SOE agents sit in the 161 squadron Short Stirlings?

Tags: world-war-two, 20th-century, aircraft, aviation

If this question is better suited for a more aviation-oriented forum, please let me know.

---

During World War II SOE agents were dropped into occupied Europe by No. 161 squadron of the RAF. This squadron used the Short Stirling bomber up until March 1945.

In the Short Stirling, the pilots were separated from the flight engineer and wireless operator. There is also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Short_Stirling_-_Royal_Air_Force_Transport_Command,_1943-1945._CH16483.jpg) picture on Wikipedia, which appears to show the interior of a modified Short Stirling that could carry passengers?

My question would be: In a typical 161 squadron mission, where in the Short Stirling would the agent(s) be located?

---

**EDIT:** I've reposted this question to [Aviation Stackexchange](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/68211/where-did-the-soe-agents-sit-in-the-161-squadron-short-stirlings) and have received an answer there.

Comment: I think this would very likely get better answers on Aviation.SE